# Flutter FirebaseAuthException error code always 'unknown' - what's wrong?

Tags: flutter, firebase, try-catch

I'm learning Flutter and I'm faced with a situation that I don't understand. I have this code :

```
try {
                        final userCredentials = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: email, password: password);
                        print(userCredentials);
                      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (err) {
                        if (err.code == 'user-not-found') {
                          print("User not found");
                        } else if (err.code == 'wrong-password') {
                          print("Wrong password");
                        }
                      }
```

But for a reason that I don't understand the err.code only return the value 'unknown', anyone ever had the same issue ?

Thanks in advance for the response !

Changed the error variable, checked the FirebaseAuth documentation for the error code.

Comment: Have you tried checking err.message instead of err.code? I use err.message in my Flutter app with a similar try {} on FirebaseAuthException catch (err) {} block and I have never had any issues with it (the message values have been accurate). I have not tried err.code but am curious what your err.message values are.

Comment: I've tried both at the moment, when I use the e.code I will get the value unknown returned and when I try e.code I will get "An unknown error occurred: FirebaseError: Firebase: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password. (auth/wrong-password)". Still trying some things to figure it out.

Comment: Ok. e.message is telling you what the issue is then.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are trying to run in web, if you are trying to run in web (debug mode) always the error will be unknown. My solution is to run on mobile or web (release mode), that worked for me.

Debug:

[image: Debug]

Release:

[image: Release]

Comment: Hey ! yeah you were right it was because of the platform. In the end what I did is to add a regex to the whole message to find the error title. Seem to work for now. But thanks a lot !